# Android colorful notification pictures

Tags: android, icons, android-notifications

I want to implement colorful, customized notification in my Android App.

I tried to implement color, but for the moment I can only set the background color. I want to reach this kind of result:
[image]

With a image of my app shown as a notification pic when expanded.

Here my code at the moment:

```
return builder.setContentTitle("APP TITLE")
                .setContentText("Some texts")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setAutoCancel(true)        
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

How can I implement the icon notification colorful, as the hangouts example I posted above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(messs)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.hangouts_launcher)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
 // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light           
        int defaults = 0;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
        // Set the content for Notification
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(messs);
 mNotificationManager.notify(m, mNotifyBuilder.build());
```